# FCFS algorithm using C++

Tags: c++, operating-system, scheduling

How can I write and run a FCFS algorithm using C++
knowing that these are the input info:

Process ,burst time , waiting time
(p1=burst 24 , wt 0)

(p2=burst 15 = wt 24)

(p3=burst 27, wt 39)

(p4=burst 16, wt 66)

(p5=burst 16, wt 82)

( average waiting time =61.8)

average of turn around time = 19.6

Comment: Something with a push + pop functions could do that.

Comment: stack<int> mystack; for(int i=0;i<5;i++)mystack.push(P[i]); and then mystack.top(); one by one

Comment: huseyin tugrul buyukisik thanks , but could you help me please to write that code !

Comment: Are you talking about real processes or variables named "process"es?

Comment: variables named process P1, P2, P3, P4,P5

Comment: Q: what have you tried?

Comment: huseyin you're my hero ,, thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You've not shown any evidence of trying to solve the problem. This tends to prejudice people against your question. How long does P1 have to wait before it can be scheduled? P2, P3, P4, P5?  So, what is the average wait time? What is the turnaround time for P1? P2, P3, P4, P5? So, what is the average turnaround time? If you can't find the answers to those questions, you need to go back and reread the lecture notes (or read them, or the text book). If you can answer the questions, you can code a program using an array of the times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a FCFS algorithms using c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461201/how-to-make-a-fcfs-algorithms-using-c)

Comment: Process ,burst time , waiting time
(p1=burst 24 , wt 0), (p2=burst 15 = wt 24), (p3=burst 27, wt 39) (p4=burst 16, wt 66) (p5=burst 16, wt 82) and ( average waiting time =61.8)   average of turn around time = 19.6

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Just sort the processes according to their waiting time (wt). And calculate the burst time. Please provide a better input set. Your current input doesn't need any sorting.

On other note, please try to understand what the algorithm says. In FCFS, the processes (P1...Pn) will be processed in a order according to their entering time in CPU. Who comes first will be served first as the name says.

Comment: i did that already and i've calculated everything.. thank you